# I have error in my php file which contain error Array to string conversion and Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, database

Here is the file, I am facing this issue
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php on line 46 Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php on line 46 Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php on line 46 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php:46 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php(46): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\backhaul-dispatcher\login\process.php on line 46

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['userlogin'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
}
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1-rc.1/css/select2.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prospect.css">
    <title>Add New prospect | BackHaul Dispatcher</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BackHaul Dispatcher</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="add-new-prospect.php">Add New prospect</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="prospect-details.php">prospect Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?logout=true">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="add-new-prospect.php" method="post">
            <div class="container row g-3">
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-5 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="client_first_name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_first_name" name="client_first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-5 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="client_last_name" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_last_name" name="lient_last_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-5 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="phone_number" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phone_number">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="client_email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="client_email" name="client_email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="client_address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_address" name="client_address" placeholder="city, state, or zip code">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="mc_number" class="form-label">M.C Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mc_number" name="mc_number">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="speciality" class="form-label">Speciality</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="where_haul">Where do you Haul?</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-select" id="where_haul" name="where_haul">
                        <option value="interstate">Intersate</option>
                        <option value="intrastate">Intrastate</option>
                        <option value="usa_ca">USA/CA</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 " id="interstate">
                    <label for="interstate_option">Intersate</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-select select-multiple" multiple="multiple" id="interstate_option" name="interstate_option">
                        <option value="state" selected disabled>Select state</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 " id="intrastate">
                    <label for="intrastate_option">Intrastate</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-select select-multiple" multiple="multiple" id="intrastate_option" name="intrastate_option">
                        <option value="state" selected >Select state</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 " id="usa_ca">
                    <label for="usa_ca_option">USA/CA</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-select select-multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usa_ca_option" name="usa_ca_option">
                        <option value="state" selected>Select state</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="equipment" class="form-label">Equipment</label>
                    <select id="equipment" name="equipment" class="form-select">
                        <optgroup label="Trailer Type">
                            <option value="dry-van" selected>Dry Van</option>
                            <option value="reefer">Reefer</option>
                            <option value="double-drop">Double Drop</option>
                            <option value="lowboy">Lowboy</option>
                            <option value="step-dack">Step-Dack</option>
                            <option value="hotshot">Hotshot</option>
                            <option value="flat-bed">Flat-Bed</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Box Truck">
                            <option value="straight-box-truck">Straight</option>
                            <option value="reefer-box-truck">Reefer</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Power Only">
                            <option value="xl">XL</option>
                            <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
                            <option value="xxxl">XXXL</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="solo_team" class="form-label">Do you drive Solo or team?</label>
                    <select id="solo_team" name="solo_team" class="form-select">
                        <option value="solo">Solo</option>
                        <option value="team">Team</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <p class="pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">Other Equipment</p>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="chain" name="chain" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="chain">
                        Chain
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="lift_gate" name="lift_gate">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="lift_gate">
                        Lift Gate
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="swing_doors" name="swing_doors">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="swing_doors">
                        Swing Doors
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="blanket" name="blanket">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="blanket">
                        Blanket
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="wooden_floor" name="wooden_floor">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="wooden_floor">
                        Wooden Floor
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-2 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ramp" name="ramp">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ramp">
                        Ramp
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check col-md-4 pt-2 ps-5 pe-2 ">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="dock_high" name="dock_high">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="dock_high">
                        Dock High
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="no_drivers" class="form-label">No. of Drivers</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_drivers" name="no_drivers">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="no_power_units" class="form-label">No. of Power Units</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_power_units" name="no_power_units">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="no_trailer" class="form-label">No. of Trailer</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="no_trailer" name="no_trailer">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="length_trailer" class="form-label">Length of trailer</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length_trailer" name="length_trailer" placeholder="Feet">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="min_weight" class="form-label">Min. Weight</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min_weight" name="min_weight" placeholder="lbs">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-2 ps-2 pe-2 ">
                    <label for="max_weight" class="form-label">Max. Weight</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max_weight" name="max_weight" placeholder="lbs">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 pt-3 ps-2 pe-2 pb-5">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1-rc.1/js/select2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
                var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
                if (valid) {
                    var client_first_name = $('#client_first_name').val();
                    var client_last_name = $('#client_last_name').val();
                    var client_email = $('#client_email').val();
                    var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val();
                    var client_address = $('#client_address').val();
                    var mc_number = $('#mc_number').val();
                    var speciality = $('#speciality').val();
                    var where_haul = $('#where_haul').val();
                    var interstate_option = $('#interstate_option').val();
                    var intrastate_option = $('#intrastate_option').val();
                    var usa_ca_option = $('#usa_ca_option').val();
                    var equipment = $('#equipment').val();
                    var solo_team = $('#solo_team').val();
                    var chain = $('#chain').val();
                    var tarps = $('#tarps').val();
                    var binders = $('#binders').val();
                    var pallet_jack = $('#pallet_jack').val();
                    var air_ride = $('#air_ride').val();
                    var hazmat = $('#hazmat').val();
                    var sides = $('#sides').val();
                    var coil_rack = $('#coil_rack').val();
                    var load_bar = $('#load_bar').val();
                    var dunnage = $('#dunnage').val();
                    var lift_gate = $('#lift_gate').val();
                    var swing_doors = $('#swing_doors').val();
                    var blanket = $('#blanket').val();
                    var wooden_floor = $('#wooden_floor').val();
                    var ramp = $('#ramp').val();
                    var dock_high = $('#dock_high').val();
                    var no_drivers = $('#no_drivers').val();
                    var no_power_units = $('#no_power_units').val();
                    var no_trailer = $('#no_trailer').val();
                    var length_trailer = $('#length_trailer').val();
                    var min_weight = $('#min_weight').val();
                    var max_weight = $('#max_weight').val();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'process.php',
                        data: {
                            client_first_name: client_first_name,
                            client_last_name: client_last_name,
                            client_email: client_email,
                            phone_number: phone_number,
                            client_address: client_address,
                            mc_number: mc_number,
                            speciality: speciality,
                            where_haul: where_haul,
                            interstate_option: interstate_option,
                            intrastate_option: intrastate_option,
                            usa_ca_option: usa_ca_option,
                            equipment: equipment,
                            solo_team: solo_team,
                            chain: chain,
                            tarps: tarps,
                            pallet_jack: pallet_jack,
                            binders: binders,
                            air_ride: air_ride,
                            hazmat: hazmat,
                            sides: sides,
                            coil_rack: coil_rack,
                            load_bar: load_bar,
                            dunnage: dunnage,
                            lift_gate: lift_gate,
                            swing_doors: swing_doors,
                            blanket: blanket,
                            wooden_floor: wooden_floor,
                            ramp: ramp,
                            dock_high: dock_high,
                            no_drivers: no_drivers,
                            no_power_units: no_power_units,
                            no_trailer: no_trailer,
                            length_trailer: length_trailer,
                            min_weight: min_weight,
                            max_weight: max_weight
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                'title': 'Successful',
                                'text': data,
                                'type': 'success'
                            })
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                'title': 'Errors',
                                'text': 'There were error while saving data.',
                                'type': 'error'
                            })
                        }

                    });
                } else {

                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    



</body>

</html>
```

---

and config.php file

```
   <?php

$db_user ="root";
$db_pass ="";
$db_name ="registration";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

---

and process.php file

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $client_first_name = $_POST['client_first_name'];
    $client_last_name = $_POST['client_last_name'];
    $client_email = $_POST['client_email'];
    $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $client_address = $_POST['client_address'];
    $mc_number = $_POST['mc_number'];
    $speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
    $where_haul = $_POST['where_haul'];
    $interstate_option = $_POST['interstate_option'];
    $intrastate_option = $_POST['intrastate_option'];
    $usa_ca_option = $_POST['usa_ca_option'];
    $equipment = $_POST['equipment'];
    $solo_team = $_POST['solo_team'];
    $chain = $_POST['chain'];
    $tarps = $_POST['tarps'];
    $binders = $_POST['binders'];
    $pallet_jack = $_POST['pallet_jack'];
    $air_ride = $_POST['air_ride'];
    $hazmat = $_POST['hazmat'];
    $sides = $_POST['sides'];
    $coil_rack = $_POST['coil_rack'];
    $load_bar = $_POST['load_bar'];
    $dunnage = $_POST['dunnage'];
    $lift_gate = $_POST['lift_gate'];
    $swing_doors = $_POST['swing_doors'];
    $blanket = $_POST['blanket'];
    $wooden_floor = $_POST['wooden_floor'];
    $ramp = $_POST['ramp'];
    $dock_high = $_POST['dock_high'];
    $no_drivers = $_POST['no_drivers'];
    $no_power_units = $_POST['no_power_units'];
    $no_trailer = $_POST['no_trailer'];
    $length_trailer = $_POST['length_trailer'];
    $min_weight = $_POST['min_weight'];
    $max_weight = $_POST['max_weight'];
    // $authority_letter = $_POST['authority_letter'];
    // $w9 = $_POST['w9'];
    // $certificate_insurance = $_POST['certificate_insurance'];
    // $other_files = $_POST['other_files'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prospects (client_first_name,client_last_name,client_email,phone_number,client_address,mc_number,speciality,where_haul,interstate_option,intrastate_option,usa_ca_option,equipment,solo_team,chain,tarps,binders,pallet_jack,air_ride,hazmat,sides,coil_rack,load_bar,dunnage,lift_gate,swing_doors,blanket,wooden_floor,ramp,dock_high,no_drivers,no_power_units,no_trailer,length_trailer,min_weight,max_weight) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sql);
/** LINE 46 **/ $result = $stmtinsert->execute([$client_first_name, $client_last_name, $client_email, $phone_number, $client_address, $mc_number, $speciality, $where_haul, $interstate_option, $intrastate_option, $usa_ca_option, $equipment, $solo_team, $chain, $tarps, $binders, $pallet_jack, $air_ride, $hazmat, $sides, $coil_rack, $load_bar, $dunnage, $lift_gate, $swing_doors, $blanket, $wooden_floor, $ramp, $dock_high, $no_drivers, $no_power_units, $no_trailer, $length_trailer, $min_weight, $max_weight]);
    if ($result) {
        echo 'Successfully Submitted';
    } else {
        echo 'There were error while saving data.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Data';
}
```

Comment: intrastate_option I think this is the problem. How can you have 2 columns with same name

Comment: Dear,one is intrastate_option and other is interstate_option

Comment: okay, I checked again yes it is. you need to check that type and values in $interstate_option and $intrastate_option, if it's an array then you need to convert it into string , maybe json_encode can help

Comment: also, the values array has one extra entry `$sql = "INSERT INTO prospects (35) VALUES(36)";`, not sure if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You have select inputs allowing multiple values (exe: "interstate_option"), so in your PHP script *$_POST['interstate_option']* is a array. You'r passing the value of *$_POST['interstate_option']* to the PDO, wich is expecting a string.

Comment: If you need to accept more than one value for the inputs, you'll have to change everything. Starting with your database, creating other tables with relation 1-n where you can save many rows related to one prospect (look up "database normalization"). Then you'll have to do one insert for the prospect and one for each value.
However, if you dont need multiple select values, just remove the multiple="multiple" from your html.